# How properly manually to switch between View Controllers in Storyboard (is iOS)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I know that this question is asked but I don't get the whole picture.

I am using Storyboard with segues, because my App navigation is straight forward (I don't use Navigation Controller). My problem is that there are a few cases in which I have to switch back to another View Controller (not to that from which I  originally came from, but linear through several View Controllers).

At this moment I use unwind segue and go through controllers back. As I understand I can use segue on event `viewDidAppear` (otherwise it is not working). This causes view controllers to appear one after another which is not very sensible.

I understand that there are methods which manually allow to switch to another View Controller. In that case I am not sure what will happened with segue in memory.

So what is the recommended way to deal with this situation?

**EDIT**

I think I not described in many details my case:

1. I use manual custom segue (wind and unwind).
2. My logic of View Controllers looks like:

A -> B -> D

A -> C -> D

A ------> D

In most cases I move forward and backward (by 1 step). There are few cases in which I have to go from D to A through B for example. I make 2 unwinds to do that. My problem is that to make unwind work I have to put it in `viewDidAppear` event (otherwise it is not working - there was a question about that also). So I go back from D - the screen shows B with animation and after that I unwind once again and I open A with animation - it is not practical and looks bad.

So I want to know that I can open A from D not with segue (I know that it is possible)? I want to know how this will affect unwind segue. As I understand it is kept into memory. I am also not sure that this will not break segue chain if I try to go forth once again (from A through B to D)?

Comment: Are you wanting to go from VCA -> vc B -> VC X ? (Which has no segue from vcB? ) If so, you can manually present the view controller if the current view controller is part of UiNavigation Controller

Comment: I updated question - I not use navigation controller. My app has specific look and I am not familiar if I can use hidden navigation controller. I use manual segue management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect the unwind segues from the controller itself, and call performSegueWithIdentifier when you want to go back. This is no different from what you would do with a forward segue if you want to call one manually in code. When and where you call performSegueWithIdentifier depends on the logic of your app; usually, you would call it in response to some user action.

Comment: Hi @rdelmar, I already to that. My problem is when I have to unwind. As I understand I can unwind only backwards. If I have vc A -> vc B -> vc D I will wind from A -> B and B -> D. Then I will unwind from D -> B and from B -> A. But I need to unwind from D -> A without making that unwind to B visible on the screen.

Comment: @new2ios, you should be able to unwind directly from D to A without going through B. Are you using Apple's unwind segue, or are you using a custom segue for your unwinds? There's no reason you should have to put an unwind segue in viewDidAppear. You need to give more detail about what you're doing, and post the code for any custom segues you're doing.

Comment: Sorry @rdelmar, I made a little mess. Actually I have 2 scenarios: **1st** I have to skip vc A and go directly to vc B in the beginning - this is after the activation step (I always start from Activation step - vc A). Here I move through `viewDidAppear` **2nd** I need to return from vc D directly to vc A skipping vc B (I previously wind through vc B). I don't know if 2nd is possible because unwind brings me back to previous vc. I don't know if I can set destination and source manually before unwind.

Comment: @new2ios, you can unwind directly to any previous controller in the path you used to go forward. How are you setting up your unwind segues? I'll ask again; are you using the standard unwind, or are you using a custom one you made?

Comment: I use :`[[self sourceViewController] presentModalViewController:[self destinationViewController] animated:YES];` and `[[self destinationViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: nil];` in custom segue. Actually I start with more code but then remove custom transition. So I think I use standard segue management.

Comment: @new2ios, that is not an unwind segue. I don't know if you can even make a custom unwind (at least one that is as general as Apple's). If you want to go from D to A, then use a real unwind segue.

Comment: Obviously I am not doing it right. 10x for the info. I will read more about that topic.

Comment: I understand my mistake, @rdelmar. I used custom code to unwind segue. Then I make changes and remove animation effects, but in that change I just replace unwind with dismiss view controller. I will fix this.

Answer (score 0):

If you using UINavigationController to switch between viewControllers,

```
NSArray *viewControllersStack = [[self navigationController] viewControllers];
UIViewController *controller = viewControllersStack[<needed index>];
[[self navigationController] popToViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

In any method of view controller which called after and include 
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated

Comment: I am not using navigation controller @mityaika07.

Answer (score 0):

In This case I recommend to subclass of  UINavigationController with custom animation delegate and inside do that:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.delegate = [MainNavigationBarDelegate instance];
}
```

Main NavigationBarDelegate.h:

```
@interface MainNavigationBarDelegate : NSObject <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>

+ (instancetype)instance;

@end
```

MainNavigationBarDelegate.m:

```
#import "MainNavigationBarDelegate.h"

@implementation MainNavigationBarDelegate

+ (instancetype)instance
{
    static MainNavigationBarDelegate *delegate;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        delegate = [[MainNavigationBarDelegate alloc] init];
    });

    return delegate;
}


- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC
{
    return self;
}

- (NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    return 0.3;
}
- (void)animateTransition:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{ 
    RootViewController *fromViewController = (RootViewController*)[transitionContext     viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    RootViewController *toViewController = (RootViewController*)[transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

    NSUInteger fromIndex = [toViewController.navigationController.childViewControllers indexOfObject:fromViewController];
    NSUInteger toIndex = [toViewController.navigationController.childViewControllers indexOfObject:toViewController];
    BOOL scrollRight = toIndex > fromIndex;

    // Get the size of the view area. 
    [transitionContext.containerView addSubview:fromViewController.view];
    [transitionContext.containerView addSubview:toViewController.view];


    CGFloat xOrigin;
    if (scrollRight){
        xOrigin = fromViewController.view.frame.size.width;
    }
    else {
        xOrigin = -fromViewController.view.frame.size.width;
    }
    toViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin, toViewController.view.frame.origin.y, toViewController.view.frame.size.width, toViewController.view.frame.size.height);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] animations:^{    
        toViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, toViewController.view.frame.origin.y, toViewController.view.frame.size.width, toViewController.view.frame.size.height);
        fromViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(-xOrigin, fromViewController.view.frame.origin.y, fromViewController.view.frame.size.width, fromViewController.view.frame.size.height);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [transitionContext completeTransition:YES]; 

        if (scrollRight){
            fromViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, fromViewController.view.frame.origin.y, fromViewController.view.frame.size.width, fromViewController.view.frame.size.height);
            [toViewController.navigationController.view addSubview:fromViewController.view];
            [toViewController.navigationController.view sendSubviewToBack:fromViewController.view];
        }
    }];
}



@end
```